# In entity framework 4.1, Is there a better way to find subpages using a URL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am setting up a page and sub-page system for a site. So, let's say there is an "Index" page, with a "Sub" page. To access the sub page the URL would look like this: "Index/Sub".

There could another page with "Sub" for the URL part. IE: "Index/Sub" and "AnotherPage/Sub".
In ASP.NET MVC, I am taking a URL and splitting it into an array on forward slashes. Then I use EF4.1 to find the correct page entity.

As I look at the code, it works, but I'm wondering if I can reduce the number of calls to the database. Here's my test action:

```
    public string Index(string url)
    {
        // split url into array
        string[] slugs = url.Split('/');
        string currentSlug = slugs[0];

        // set starting page and loop
        Page page = db.Pages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Slug == currentSlug);
        for (var i = 1; i < slugs.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(slugs[i]) 
                && page != null 
                && page.Children != null)
            {
                page = page.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Slug == slugs[i]);
            }
        }

        // if null return 404
        if(page == null) throw new HttpException(404, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");

        // return page
        return page.Label;
    }
```

Is this scary or alright? Is there a way to reduce the potential number of db calls?

-Thanks for any tips-

#### Edit

Here's my Page model FYI

```
public class Page
{
    public Guid PageId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "URL is required")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Must be less than 30 characters")]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Label is required")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Must be less than 30 characters")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Must be less than 100 characters")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Must be less than 255 characters")]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "Must be less than 300 characters")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    public string LayoutName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }

    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Page> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd certainly include the full page path on each `Page`, so you can do the query in one db call. (Yes, then the data will not be fully normalised in the DB, but that a sacrifice we sometimes have to make for the sake of performance). Just make sure you have a strategy to update sub pages when ever a parent page changes.

If you dislike the idea of a full path column on the pages, perhaps you should cache the paths and the page ID's they resolve to, instead of asking the DB each time (Remember to have a cache clearing strategy).